# count по разным группировкам в одном запросе

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли в одном запросе с двумя вложенными группировками получить сразу количество записей в каждой внешней и каждой внутренней группировке?
Например, для таблицы с полями:

ФИО жителя, район, город

получить одним запросом результат вида:

ФИО жителя, район, город, количество жителей в этом районе, количество жителей в этом городе.

Comment: Посмотрите http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html , модификатор ROLLUP

По другому 

     select a.FIO, a.REGION, a.CITY, b.REGION_CNT, c.CITY_CNT
     from tab a join (select REGION, CITY, count(*) REGION_CNT
      from tab
      group by REGION, CITY) b on a.REGION = b.REGION
        and a.CITY = b.CITY join 
     (select CITY, count(*) CITY_CNT from tab group by CITY) c
     on a.CITY = c.CITY;

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли.

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария:

---

Посмотрите [документацию про модификатор ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html).

По другому:

```
select a.FIO, a.REGION, a.CITY, b.REGION_CNT, c.CITY_CNT
from tab a
join (
  select REGION, CITY, count() REGION_CNT
  from tab
  group by REGION, CITY
) b
on a.REGION = b.REGION and a.CITY = b.CITY
join (
  select CITY, count() CITY_CNT
  from tab
  group by CITY
) c
on a.CITY = c.CITY;
```